# Possibility of the conversion of sql data to nosql with nodejs

Tags: sql, node.js, database, nosql

Is there any possibility of converting sql data to nosql schema and then saving it in mongo collections with nodejs??

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT *  
 FROM table_name  
 FOR JSON AUTO
```

Use the above query to get SQL data in JSON format. Then insert the JSON in Mongodb using `db.collection.insertMany()`

For more info:

- [Format Query Results as JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2014)
- [Inserts multiple documents into a
  collection.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/)